Kivy cannot be imported although using kivy or kivy[full]
i can't import kivy
i had installed several of times but is still showing ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
i try to install  kivy and kivy[full] but is still presented Required  already satisfied on the command prompt. But with the code cannot be imported.

Are you sure you are using the same python where you installed kivy? If you installed kivy using pip, try running pip -V. It should tell you which python pip is run under.
